# Jquery before() with animation

Tags: jquery, before-filter

I'm trying to make appear the result of an ajax request using before(). It works very well, but now I'd like to make appear the result with animation (toggle, slidedown or something).

Here is the code I use:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/postcom",
  dataType: "text",
  data: myData,
  success: function(response) {
    $("#results_com").before(response);
    $("#formcomtext").val('');
  },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    console.log(thrownError);
  }
});
```

html:

```
<div id="results_com></div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you use `insertBefore`, it might be easier:

```
$(response).insertBefore("#results_com").animate({}, 400);
```

Comment: Try `.hide()` after the insert. I was just giving you a way to keep the chain going instead of having to traverse the new dom. Alternatively, use CSS to hide whatever `results` is, and use jquery to animate it.

Comment: I tried $(response).insertBefore("#results_com").hide().animate({}, 400); but now it doesn't work anymore (nothing is inserted by ajax)

Answer (score 0):

You should just hide `#results_com` before animating it in. Here's a simple demo for it: http://jsfiddle.net/pERgk/

Comment: No it doesn't. Click "run" when you're on the page. It just happens quickly.

Comment: Yes, I know, I spoke about my page. It doesn't work with $('#results_com').append(response).fadeIn('slow');

Comment: Then there's something else wrong with your code. You're not giving enough details. Just saying "it doesn't work" doesn't contribute anything.

Answer (score 0):

working Demohttp://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/pERgk/2/

you can use `toggle` instead of `slideDown`

```
$('#results_com').click(function () {
    $('#results_com').hide().before('This will be the result').slideDown('slow');
});
```

Comment: jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/postcom",
            dataType:"text",
            data:myData,
            success:function(response){
            $('#results_com').hide().before(response).slideDown('slow');
            $("#formcom").toggle('slow');
            $("#formcomtext").val('');
      },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                console.log(thrownError);
            }
        });